# Problem to open Multi Threading sessions with IPs

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading

I want to write script to scan subnet, take List of IPs and open Multi-Thread sessions to scan ALL those IPs in same time for open ports:

```
import socket
import subprocess
import sys
import threading

from netaddr import IPNetwork
from datetime import datetime


List_IP = ['33.45.48.0','33.45.48.1' ]


def subnet_port_scan(subnet):
 
   remoteServerIP = socket.gethostbyname(subnet)

   sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
   result = sock.connect_ex((subnet, 22))

   if result == 0:
       print ("Port 22 is Open", subnet)
       sock.close()
   else: 
       print ("Port 22 is Closed", subnet)
       sock.close()


for function in List_IP:
   my_thread = threading.Thread(target=subnet_port_scan,args=List_IP)

   my_thread.start()

   print("Session")


my_thread.join()
```

Right now if i use more then 1 argument in List_IP it shows me error:

```
TypeError: subnet_port_scan() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I need to be able to use 10-100 IPs and open sessions with all if them at same time, but i don't understand how to do that.
Please have a look and let me know what i'm missing.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're passing in each var in the list as an argument, aka 2 arguments. You can add each thread to a list, start them all, and then join them all which is generally how I use multiprocessing. Try something like this to give you an idea of how that might work--

```
import threading

print('start')
List_IP = ['33.45.48.0','33.45.48.1' ]
threads = []

def subnet_port_scan(subnet):
  print("thread called: ", subnet)

for x in List_IP:
  my_thread = threading.Thread(target=subnet_port_scan, args=(x,))
  threads.append(my_thread)

for y in threads:
  print('starting', y)
  y.start()

for z in threads:
  print('joining ', z)
  z.join()

print("Session")
```

Comment: Thank you, i did work on it more and found solution.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution:

for function in List_IP:
my_thread = threading.Thread(target=subnet_port_scan,args=(function, ))
my_thread.start()

Did not put proper arguments.